# Can the events of Endgame be seen in other MCU movies?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

One of my friends told me that in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, you could see War Machine and Nebula in 2014 on Morag, when Star-Lord was dancing. I haven't gone back to rewatch GotG 1 yet, but I wondered if anyone could confirm this. Also, are there any other instances in previous MCU movies that the 2023 versions of the Avengers can be seen?

Comment: that would imply that the directors had the whole plot of the MCU mapped out which i very much doubt because that's one of the reasons i keep hearing why the MCU successes while the DCEU failed

Comment: @Memor-X while I agree they probably didn't know all the details, I have to say: "Huh?!!" How would you hear that the DCEU having it all planned out while the MCU doesn't is the reason they fail?? If anything the DC guys seem to have far less of an over-arching plan than the Marvel guys. Marvel might not have all the details down, but at least they had/have a pretty far-reaching rough plan on where they would like to go - and yes, hash out the details and adapt it on the go. While the DC guys seem to barely think about the next movie plotwise, just knowing that they're gonna make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interview with the Russo Brothers: https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-ending-russo-brothers-on-captain-america-iron-man/

where they talk about this:

> Q: [Endgame’s] plot, is it a parallel universe or a closed time loop?
>
> A: Nope, not a time loop. Both Ancient One and Hulk were right. You
>   can’t change the future by simply going back to past. But it’s
>   possible to create a different alternate future. It’s not butterfly
>   effect. Every decision you made in the past could potentially create a
>   new timeline. For example, the old Cap at the end movie, he lived his
>   married life in a different universe from the main one. He had to make
>   another jump back to the main universe at the end to give the shield
>   to Sam.

I'd like to stress on the line:

> Every decision you made in the past could potentially create a new timeline.

... not just taking of the Infinity Stone

When Rhodes and Nebula went back to 2014, to Morag, the event them being there causes the two Nebulas to interlink. This event creates a new timeline. This timeline is different from the Original Timeline where the events of GOTG vol.1 takes place. The Original timeline does not have the future Rhodes or Nebula in Morag in 2014. Also, there is no such scene in the GOTG film. Your friend is messing with you :)

To add. the timeline that was created because of the Nebulas will continue to exist even after Steve returns the Power Stone because taking of the Power Stone is not what caused that timeline in the first place. In this timeline you will not have Thanos because he went to the Original Timeline to 2023 and died. So the movie GOTG vol 1 would not play out the way it did without Thanos.

Answer (score 7):

For in-universe, the answer should be **NO**

All the movies before *Avengers: Endgame* follow the Universal Timeline. In *Avengers: Endgame*, when the Avengers go back in time, they create branches in the the Universal Timeline. All this branches will have new realities (and movies) now but thankfully, all of them are clipped at the end of the movie, when the stones are returned.

So, in the Universal Timeline, in which earlier movies exist, there is no possibility of such a thing happening.

For out-of-universe, there may be a possibility of such Easter eggs. But I doubt it. The entire MCU path wasn't planned from the start. Also different directors made different movies.

Comment: As Prof Hulk demonstrated, the temporal disruption in each timeline was temporary in nature.